# How to append a div with different input types using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript. Right now I'm building a form. The user should be able to ad a new person via button one. How am I able to do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $(".container").append(".wrapper"); // How to insert the whole wrapper? 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="button1">Ad one person </button>
  <div class="wrapper" id="person1">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Surename" required>
    <input type="date" class="input" placeholder="Birthday" required onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='Birthday')">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the entire html like this `$(".container").append($(".wrapper").html());`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".container").append($(".wrapper").html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="button1">Ad one person </button>
  <div class="wrapper" id="person1">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Surename" required>
    <input type="date" class="input" placeholder="Birthday" required onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='Birthday')" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for youre answer :D Do I have to insert the html into the two brackets after the .html?